# Свой header(.h) и компиляция нескольких файлов

Tags: c++, cmd, mingw, header, g++

Я разделил свою программу на три файла. Все они находятся **в одной папке** и 
запускаются в компиляторе g++ как `g++ main.cpp pkv.cpp pkv.h`

Но выдает ошибку - скорее всего, я неправильно заполнил  файлы *pkv.cpp pkv.h*. Если написать функцию `to_dec()` просто в `main.cpp`, то всё работает

В код сильно не смотрите: у меня он другой,а это упрощенная модель.

```
//main.cpp
//
//
#include <iostream>
#include "pkv.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    string example = "1 5 20 15 3 -6 -19"
    double res_dec = to_dec(example);               //TO_DEC() - требуемая функция

    cout <<  "RESULT in DECIMAL: " << setprecision(30) << res_dec << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Второй файл

```
// pkv.cpp
//
//
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string> 

double to_dec(string pkv) {
  double decimal;
  short sign = atoi(pkv.substr(0, 1).c_str());
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    pkv.erase(0, pkv.find(' ') + 1);
  }
  while (pkv.find(' ') != -1) {
    decimal += pow(2, atoi(pkv.substr(0, pkv.find(' ')).c_str()));
    pkv.erase(0, pkv.find(' ') + 1);
  }
  decimal += pow(2, atoi(pkv.c_str()));

  return pow(-1, sign) * decimal;
}
```

И Третий

```
// pkv.h
//
//
#ifndef PKV_H
#define PKV_H

double to_dec(string pkv);

#endif
```

Comment: `g++ main.cpp pkv.cpp` должно хватить - ну, в плане - заголовочные файлы отдельно компилировать не к чему...

Comment: Компилятору не нужно передавать хэдэр файл, ему нужно знать только то, где его искать

Comment: И что за ошибка?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch 

PKV.H: ERROR: 'string' was not declared in this scope
MAIN.CPP: ERROR: 'to_dec' cannot be used as a function

P.S. Запускаю уже без pkv.h

Comment: Ну правильно, в `main.cpp` и в `pkv.h` используется `std::string`, однако `#include <string>` отсутствует.

Comment: Да, но я добавил его в pkv.cpp - думал, что этого хватит

Comment: Почему вы так думали?

Answer (score 1):

1) в вашем хэдэре используется некий string. Что это - компилятору никак не может быть известно.

2) ваш cpp файл с определением вашей функции никак не ссылается на ваш хэдэрфайл с объявлением функции

3) вам это уже написал компилятор. Почему вы не читаете что он вам говорит для меня загадка.